# concerning big-oh notation and proving or disproving

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, notation

So I'm completely lost on big-oh notation.

In my assignment I am supposed to prove or disprove the following using the formal definition.

```
3n³ - 7n² + 100n - 36 is in O(n³)
```

and

```
n²/log(n) + 3n is in O(n²)
```

Can someone help me with these and tell me how to go about proving or disproving.

Comment: This might be suitable for math.stackexchange.com, because you are asking how to perform a proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

The [definition of Big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) is

> `f(n) ∈ O(g(n))      ⇔      lim supn → ∞ | f(n)/g(n) | < ∞`

Since your `f(n)` and `g(n)` are polynomials `lim sup` and `lim` are the same. So you have to proof:

1. `limn → ∞ |(3n³ - 7n² + 100n - 36) / n³| < ∞`

   ```
   limn → ∞ |(3n³ - 7n² + 100n - 36) / n³| 
    = limn → ∞ |n³(3 - 7/n + 100/n² - 36/n³) / n³|
    = limn → ∞ |3 - 7/n + 100/n² - 36/n³|
    = 3 < ∞
   ```
2. `lim supn → ∞ |(n²/log(n) + 3n) / n²| < ∞`

   ```
   lim supn → ∞ |(n²/log(n) + 3n) / n²| 
    = lim supn → ∞ |n²(1/log(n) + 3/n) / n²|
    = lim supn → ∞ |1/log(n) + 3/n|
    = 0 < ∞
   ```

   here you can also see that `n²/log(n) + 3n` is also in `o(n²)`.